# Compare elements of a list of lists and return a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists, I don't know the length of the main list but each 'sublist' contains necessarily 6 floats. I need to compare each float of each sublist and keep the smaller one for the first three floats and the higher one for the last three and finally, I need to return all these values in a 6-float list in the same order.

Here is an example:

```
list1 = [[-2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 2.0, 10.0, 2.0], [-1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0, 5.0, 4.0]]
# Compare list1[0][0] with list1[1][0]
# Will return -2.0 (because the index is between 0 and 2 so it returns the lower float)
# Compare list1[0][4] with list1[1][4]
# Will return 10.0 (because the index is between 3 and 5 so it returns the higher float)
# The final result which should be returned is:
# [-2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 2.0, 10.0, 4.0]

list2 = [[-2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 2.0, 10.0, 2.0], [-1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0, 5.0, 4.0], [3.0, 0.0, -1.0, 4.0, 1.0, 0.0]]
# Compare list2[0][2] with list2[1][2] with list2[2][2]
# Will return -2.0 (because the index is between 0 and 2 so it returns the lower float)
# The final result which should be returned is:
# [-2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 4.0, 10.0, 4.0]
```

I read about `zip()`, sets, list comprehension and different topics on this site but I couldn't achieve what I want.

Comment: 1. Add your attempts. 2. Add the *final* expected output

Comment: @ Bhargav Rao - Sorry, I added the result I expected to be returned. But I admit I gave up before having any convincing attempts...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do `zip(*list2)`, you'll create a list of the first element of each sublist together, the second elements together, etc. So you want to get the minimum value of the first 3 and the maximum value of the next 3.

```
zipped = zip(*list2)
result = [min(zipped[i]) for i in range(3)] + [max(zipped[i]) for i in range(3, 6)]
```

In Python 3 `zip()` will fetch the zipped sublists lazily like an iterator, while in Python 2 it will create the whole list in advance. This is similar to `range()` between the two version. If you want a lazy generation in Python 2, you can use the iterator version from the itertools module.

```
import itertools

zipped = itertools.izip(*list2)
result = [min(zipped.next()) for _ in range(3)] + [max(zipped.next()) for _ in range(3)]
```

**Edit**: Visual example of what [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) achieves.

```
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> zip(*a) # you need `list(zip(*a))` in Python 3
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

The star syntax unpacks the list in several arguments, so that `zip(*[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])` becomes `zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])`, which is what you want.

Comment: Thank you! The first one is perfect, more understandable for me now. But I'll also take a look at you second solution. :)

Comment: @UKDP I've updated my answer to mention that `zip()` in Python 3 behaves somewhat different. In order to understand that and `itertools.izip()`, you want to look into [iterators and generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it "manually" using 2 nested for loops

```
list1 = [[-2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 2.0, 10.0, 2.0], [-1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0, 5.0, 4.0]]
output = [0 for x in range(6)]
# iterate over the 6 numbers
for i in range(6):
    value = list1[0][i] # pick the first number
    #iterate over all the lists, if we find a bigger/smaller one our current one then save it
    for j in range(len(list1)):
        if i >= 3 and list1[j][i] > value:
                value = list1[j][i]
        elif i < 3 and list1[j][i] < value:
                value = list1[j][i]
    #put the biggest/smallest value in the correct place in the output array
    output[i] = value
print output
```

Answer (score 0):

### NumPy solution

You can use NumPy:

```
np.concatenate((np.min(a[:,:3], axis=0), np.max(a[:,3:], axis=0)))
```

### Full example

```
import numpy as np

list1 = [[-2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 2.0, 10.0, 2.0], [-1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0, 5.0, 4.0]]
list2 = [[-2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 2.0, 10.0, 2.0], [-1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0, 5.0, 4.0],
         [3.0, 0.0, -1.0, 4.0, 1.0, 0.0]]

a1 = np.array(list1)
a2 = np.array(list2)

for a in [a1, a2]:
    print(list(np.concatenate((np.min(a[:,:3], axis=0), np.max(a[:,3:], axis=0)))))
```

Prints:

```
[-2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 2.0, 10.0, 4.0]
[-2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 4.0, 10.0, 4.0]
```